Why can't I open port 9 on a Huawei WS5200 router?
When I try to do port forwarding in Huawei WS5200 router so I can use Wake on LAN even if I use not the same network as my computer, but when I put those configurations:

I still cant use WOL from another network.
I tested it form wake on lan application by Mike webb on Android using mobile internet (not the same local network)
And checked the port status using canyouseeme.org
And idk what the fuck is CGNAT
I turned off firewall.

Are you behind a CGNAT by chance?

How are you testing this? Are you trying to actually WoL, or are you testing with the computer still on?

I improved my question guys

GUYS ANSWER ME I IMPROVED MY QUESTION HELP
